# Parsing string Time to DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, format-string

I have a string time like this format "12:00 AM", I am trying to parse with DateTime.ParseExtract

```
 var begin = DateTime.ParseExact(BeginTime, "HH:mm tt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).AddHours(2);               
 var end = DateTime.ParseExact(EndTime, "HH:mm tt", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).AddHours(2);
 var isOpen = (DateTime.Now > begin && DateTime.Now < end);
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `"hh:mm tt"` as format string. `HH` indicates hours in 24-Hours format (16 = 4 PM) while `hh` indicates it in 12-Hours format.

Comment: I tried but it gives error format exception